# Redirect doesn't work in Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, response.redirect

Everything in the code below works great.  The log logs. But the redirect never happens....

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower().Trim() == "mydomain.com")
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                LogThis.WriteLog("redirecting");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(
                    string.Concat("https://mydomain.com", Request.RawUrl));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?  This is all happening in the Application_BeginRequest, in the global.asax.  It's inline code, inside a  tag.  There is no codebehind at all.

Comment: There are a number of problems with this code. The first is the string.Concat. It will redirect the user to https://mydomain.comhttp://my.domain.com/original_path. The second is the Response.Redirect, which will actually do a Response.End anyway - so the subsequent Response.End is not needed. Anyway - what happens if you just do a Response.Redirect, with no conditionals?

Comment: Hmm, `HttpContext.Current.Response.End` should not execute since `Response.Redirect` halts execution of page, but im not sure when calling with `HttpContext.Current` try removing it.

Comment: The response.end would never be reached.  It's irrelevant (part of some debugging code I had earlier). When I take it out, the behavior is the same.  I change the redirect to this: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://mydomain.com"); and nothing changes.  Thanks!

Comment: What if you instead call `((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Response.Redirect("xxx")`?

Comment: If you set a break point on the Response.Redirect does it get hit? Does it raise an error?

Comment: @pattermeister: from MSDN: "raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain information". So RawUrl would not include "http://my.domain.com".